# Thin Crashes Hard with Ramaze

Tags: ruby, thin, ramaze

So, I'm just trying out Ramaze for a new project, and I'm wondering why it won't work with Thin, but will with ramaze start (which is webrick I guess). Here's what it gives me:

/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.2/lib/thin/request.rb:50: [BUG] unknown type 0x22 (0xc given)

This is the line it's talking about:

@parser   = Thin::HttpParser.new

which isn't too helpful.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

EDIT: Actually, I remember getting this error a while back when I was trying to install the latest version of the MySQL gem. I had to reinstall it being sure to do a "make clean" before "make install". However, thin was installed from a gem, so I'm not sure how I would be able to do that here...

Answer (score 3):

It means your eventmachine was compiled with Ruby 1.8 but runs with Ruby 1.9.
Do you have a parallel installation of 1.8/1.9?

Comment: Are you sure about this? I'm having the same issue, with thin and rails. It crashes with the exact same message. I'm running OS X and eventmachine is installed via rubygems for ruby 1.9

Comment: Yeah, I do have 1.8, but I installed Thin by doing "sudo gem1.9 install thin". Unless somehow it was building against some Ruby 1.8 libs anyway.

Comment: It's very likely that it builds against Ruby 1.8 or at least requires a C-extension that was compiled against it.
AFAIK, OSX messes around with $LOAD_PATH, i don't have a machine to try this on, sorry.